# Incorrect user info with different access tokens. Tweepy

Tags: flask, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy(http://www.tweepy.org/) in a Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) application. Everything works fine and I can successfully get the tokens as well as post status updates. The problem is, when I try to change the saved twitter account (get new access tokens), though I can see it gets new access tokens, Tweepy API created with new access tokens remain the same (of the previous user). And when I do `API.me()` it's returning user info of the previous user. This is solved only after I restart the whole Flask app.

I checked the access tokens used by the API just before fetching user info. It shows different access tokens (which is correct), but the user info fetched is incorrect.

Here's a sample code showing my program logic:

```
import tweepy

c_key = "My consumer key"
c_secret = "My consumer secret"
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(c_key, c_secret)

def set_access_token(token, token_sec):
    auth.set_access_token(token, token_sec)

def get_me():
    print "access_token"
    print auth.access_token.key
    print "access_token_secret"
    print auth.access_token.secret
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    return api.me()


if __name__=="__main__":
    tokens = [("tok 1", "sec1"), ("tok2", "sec2")]
    for token in tokens:
        set_access_token(token[0], token[1])
        print get_me().screen_name


#output
user1
user1

#expected output
user1
user2
```

Am I supposed to close the connection after every operation, or something? Any help guys?

I'm **not** using Flask-Tweepy because

> http://flask-tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
>
> Flask-Tweepy 0.1 currently only supports connecting as the user who
>   registered the application (that is, you can only update the status of
>   that user). To update statuses, you will also need the Access Token
>   Key and Access Token Secret, which you can create or retrieve on the
>   Twitter Developers website.

**EDIT**:
I found a solution/workaround for this problem. If you create a new `auth` object every time, instead of just changing access tokens, it works.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    tokens = [("tok 1", "sec1"), ("tok2", "sec2")]
    for token in tokens:
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(c_key, c_secret)
        set_access_token(token[0], token[1])
        print get_me().screen_name
#output
user1
user2
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it when you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution/workaround for this problem. If you create a new auth object every time, instead of just changing access tokens, it works.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    tokens = [("tok 1", "sec1"), ("tok2", "sec2")]
    for token in tokens:
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(c_key, c_secret)
        set_access_token(token[0], token[1])
        print get_me().screen_name
#output
user1
user2
```

Though I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution since it re-creates the `auth` object every time, which doesn't seem right to me. But that's the only way I could get it to work.